# Blocking .ico files from being uploaded with NGINX

Tags: nginx, web-server

Someone keeps uploading .ico files to my wordpress sites.  I'd like to know if their is a way to block certain file types from being uploaded int eh NGINX config?

Comment: If someone is uploading files to your site without them having access, your server is compromised. Then you need to act according to https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: I want them to upload files just not ico's

Comment: If you want to limit uploadable file types, you need to look into WordPress settings / plugins.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case someone comes across this and wants a solution.  I don't think you can block just one file type in nginx but what you can do it all only certain file types in.  To do so just add

location ~ .(htm|css|jpg|gif|mp3)$ {
allow all;
}

to your NGINX config.

Comment: There is no guarantee the path being used to upload files needs to contain such extensions. Think of paths like `/upload.php?folder=image&return=True`